# Convert compilationUnit object to json in dart

Tags: json, dart, abstract-syntax-tree, dart-analyzer

Is there anyway to convert the compilationUnit object into the json?

```
String src = """
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
   runApp(new MyApp());
}
@Entity()
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.cyan),
    child: (new Center(child: new Text("Hello"))));

 }
}""";
var ast = parseCompilationUnit(src, parseFunctionBodies: true);
```

I am using this method to get the ast of the dart code and i want it to convert it into json object.

Comment: What kind of JSON object?

Comment: nested json object for the ast.

Comment: i have attached the dart code that i want to convert in ast and the in the nested json object

Comment: What should the resulting JSON look like? You need to convert it yourself. Fill a map with the keys and values and use `JSON.encode()` from the `dart:convert` package, to get a JSON string from the `Map` structure

Comment: i am new to dart so can you please tell me how to iterate AstNode object to get the keys and value. Also please explain how to use visitor for AstNode with example. Thank you..

Comment: The linter package might be helpful to get some insight how to use it https://github.com/dart-lang/linter

Comment: Thank you i will look through it and please tell about the ast to json conversion. is their and built in functions available or same way to get the nested json of the following code.

Comment: Is their any way to iterate over the AstNode object and the get all the tokens  types and value in the nested format. @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: I don't know. I never tried.

Comment: Ok, thanks @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: If you have some spare time can you please look into this. @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: nested json object for the ast. @matanlurey